# Login with phone number or email address - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, login

I created a custom attribute customer "**cm_telephone**", then i rewrite `Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` `loginPostAction()` function to customise it for login with the email or phone number. It works, just I wanted to know what you think about my code.

The code:

```
public function loginPostAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');

            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

                //the phone number condition 
                if (strpos($login['username'], '@') === false){
                    Mage::log('Customer has entered a phone number ');
                    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('cm_telephone', $login['username'])
                        ->getFirstItem();
                        if($login['username'] == $customer->getCmTelephone()){
                          $login['username'] = $customer->getEmail();
                        }
                }
                //end phone number condition
                try {
                    $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                        $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                    }
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                            $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $session->addError($message);
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                }
            } else {
                $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $this->_loginPostRedirect();
    }
```

I found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80646/is-it-possible-for-customers-to-login-with-a-customer-number-instead-of-a-email) but I didn't want to use an event and I keep the email address and I add the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is just fine. You can also remove the **if** condition:

```
if($login['username'] == $customer->getCmTelephone()){
      $login['username'] = $customer->getEmail(); 
}
```

And can use just

```
$login['username'] = $customer->getEmail();
```

Because you already have got the customer with phone number filter by your code

```
addAttributeToFilter('cm_telephone', $login['username'])
```

Comment: Hi Please have a look once at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133817/login-with-mobile-number-without-extension