# Magento | How can we make the login to be by username not email ID

Tags: magento-1.9

How can we make the login to be by username not the email?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the following module:

https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username

or you can use the logic shared by Fabian Schmengler [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80646/is-it-possible-for-customers-to-login-with-a-customer-number-instead-of-a-email).

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160373/login-with-phone-number-or-email-address-magento-1-9?noredirect=1&lq=1) also.

If you are a developer, you can take help from above links to make your own custom module.

Comment: Can you please tell us how to display the username field in the register page?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this module, this module enables to login using mobile number as well as email,  here you can use your custom attribute ( whichever you need, username / mobile ) for login :

Magento 2 :
https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-AdvancedLogin

Magento 1 :
https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username

Comment: But It Is for Magento2

Comment: I have updated answer with magento 1 module. it enables login with username and or mobile.

Comment: Can you please tell us how to display the username field in the register page?

Comment: where did you copy that module ? in your theme folder or base folder ?